# changing the color of a heading depending on the associated link? each click on each <a> should make ony that associated h2 blue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is when I click on another link the previous h2 is still blue, I want to have it so that the h2 goes back to its default color, black and that the new h2 that is associated with the link gets the color blue. I tried to use this if statement that I thought would work.

When the link is clicked it checks the color of the h2 element to see if it's blue if it is it should change it to black to imitate default. If h2's are not blue it goes to the else statement which should change the associated heading h2 to color blue. The variable "id" stores the href of the link which is the same value as the id of the h2.

```
    $("aside a").click(function(){

    if($("h2").css("color", "rgb(0,0,255)")){
        $("h2").css({"color" : "black"});
    }else{
    id = $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).css({"color" : "blue", "fontSize" : "150%"});
}
});
```

I got the code to run in the browser. the result should have the aside on the left side of the page with a list of links that are cloned from the h2s. but I can't get it to run in Jsfidle. but here is all of the code I have maybe you could tell me why it's not running in jsfidle but it runs on the browser with the html script tags etc. 
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/hPvms/)

Back to the main problem, I would like know why my if statement doesn't work. if the h2 is blue it should set the color to black if not it should change the associated h2 to blue. and if another link is clicked in the aside that associated h2 is changed to blue and all other h2 are supposed to be default black. now no colors changes why?

even though the js fiddle doesn't work it has all of the css and javascript info. The html section is missing the html and script tags because the jsfiddle said I shouldn't put it in.

[**BETTER** jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPvms/1/)

Comment: You are using the `css` method as setter not getter, it returns a jQuery object which is a truthy value in golden JavaScript.

Comment: Use classes instead of manipulating styles directly. Much easier to work with

Comment: Your jsFiddle had some syntax errors. Fxed here - http://jsfiddle.net/hPvms/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class that way you'll only need to use `.toggleClass`, but if you insist on using style... do this:

```
$("aside a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("h2 a").css('color', 'black');
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).css({'color' : 'blue', fontSize: '150%'});
});
```

**UPDATED** with using `h2 a` since your `a` tags are being assigned the ids, not the `h2` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would think that this would work but it doesn't set the other h2 elements to black for me. The previous clicked links related h2 is still blue upon click of another link. the h2 is still blue and doesn't change to black.

Comment: Strange, this should set all h2 elements on that page to black.  Maybe try:  `$("h2").css({'color', 'black !important'});` instead?  Updated answer.  But this will probably not set the current h2 to blue than...

Comment: What does the value returned from `a href` equal?

Comment: the href in the aside is supposed to equal the id of the h2 so when i click on the link it goes to the h2 that has the same id. place holder effect i think it't called.

Comment: Does `href` hava a `hashtag` in the beginning of it? First character? If the href doesn't return a hashtag in the beginning of it, than id will never work.  And you will need to append a hashtag into it.

Comment: the link of the aside has this html <a href="#heading1">Modularbook organization</a>

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it doesn't seem that any of your `<h2>` elements have an id to begin with.  Even in the jQuery, doesn't look like you are assigning any ids to the `<h2>` elements.

Comment: I just noticed that the id is being assigned to the <a> that's within the h2

Comment: $("h2 a").css('color', 'black'); seems to works.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd add some classes for defining the appearance

```
h2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 120%;
}
h2.active {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

Then simply toggle these classes via your click handler

```
var headings = $('h2');
$('aside').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    headings.removeClass('active');
    $(this.hash).addClass('active');
});
```

#### Update

Your code was a bit of a mess so I've taken the opportunity to fix it up some - http://jsfiddle.net/hPvms/5/

Your main problem was that you were injecting `<a>` tags into your headings rather than just giving the headings themselves a targetable ID attribute.

Comment: thanks for your your reply but it doesn't change the color at all, I put the css in the css file and i used the selector $("aside a"). if i just used $('aside') I got an error

Comment: Thanks for fixing the jsFiddle=

Comment: @user2537537 I've updated my answer with a working jsFiddle example